# How to use arguments passed to a custom environment in the end code of the environment?

Tags: tables, environments, miktex

I want to save some typing when I use a comon style for my tables.

But because `\caption` and `\label` have to be used inside the float, I want to pass the values for these macros via arguments into my envrionment.

I want to keep these inside the end code of my environment, to easily keep the caption at the bottom of the table.

Here is the MWE to my problem:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    a4paper
]{scrreprt}


\newenvironment{bordertab}[2]
    {
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{| l c r |}
                \hline
    }
    {
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{#1}
            \label{tab:b:#2}
        \end{table}
    }


\begin{document}
    \begin{bordertab}{A table with a border}{ex1}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bordertab}
\end{document}
```

and the errors which LaTeX throws at me when using it:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.28 ^^I\end{bordertab}

You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
<argument> \ignorespaces ##
                           1
l.28 ^^I\end{bordertab}

Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
<argument> \ignorespaces ##
                           1
l.28 ^^I\end{bordertab}

Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   2
l.28 ^^I\end{bordertab}

You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

Comment: Doing this, you'll most likely lose the autocomplete labels functionality. I would recommend you pass the whole `\label` in the second argument (in order to keep this functionality, if you care about it, of course...).

Comment: Thanks for the hint @GuilhermeZanotelli, I *do* care about this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the values in macros, which you then can use at the end of the environment.

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    a4paper
]{scrreprt}

\newcommand\bordertabA{} % make sure \bordertabA is not in use.
\newcommand\bordertabB{} % make sure \bordertabB is not in use.
\newenvironment{bordertab}[2]
    {\def\bordertabA{#1}%
     \def\bordertabB{#2}%
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{| l c r |}
                \hline
    }
    {
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{\bordertabA}
            \label{tab:b:\bordertabB}
        \end{table}
    }


\begin{document}
    \begin{bordertab}{A table with a border}{ex1}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bordertab}
\end{document}
```

Passing the arguments via macros is necessary because a definition

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[n]{begin code}{end code}
```

is roughly equivalent to the definitions

```
\newcommand\myenv[n]{begin code}
\newcommand\endmyenv{end code}
```

So the arguments are only available to the begin code. Using `#1` in the end code will lead to the error `illegal parameter number` as observed, since there are no parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm!

Can you maybe also elaborate on why it needs to be done this way (i.e. why `\caption` doen't play along with `#1`)?

Comment: @Luca I've added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have updated my question to better reflect the real cause/problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the `\caption` or the `\label` commands receiving `#` arguments. The Problem is that when you specify an Environment with arguments, the `#` have to be on the `<begin>` part of this Environment:

```
 \newenvironment{myenv}[1]{here goes #1}{no #1's here!!}
```

In light of this fact you can just put the caption on top:

```
\newenvironment{bordertab}[2]
    {
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \caption{#1}
            \label{tab:b:#2}
            \begin{tabular}{| l c r |}
                \hline
    }
    {
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    }
```

Of course this has the disadvantage of having the caption on top, when it's wished to be on the bottom. To overcome this, one can use the very useful package  `floatrow` and set all table floats to be on the bottom, additionaly, we can set an optional Parameter for `bordertab`, to reset the position to the top part. Also, `floatrow` sets all floats to `\centering` out-of-the-box, so that's no longer needed.

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    a4paper
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\newenvironment{bordertab}[3][top]
    {\floatsetup[table]{capposition=#1}
        \begin{table}
            \caption{#2}
            \label{tab:b:#3}
            \begin{tabular}{| l c r |}
                \hline
    }
    {
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    }


\begin{document}
    \begin{bordertab}{A table with a border}{ex1}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bordertab}

    \begin{bordertab}[bottom]{A tabl}{ex2}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{bordertab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful explanation and additional solution. (Altough I somehow like @gernot's solution a bit more.)